# Why does my UL list has 7 childnodes and not 3 as showing?

Tags: list, html-lists, nodes

Why does the ul with id "third" has 7 child nodes and not 3?
Nodes 1,3 and 5 are kk,gg and ff. However nodes 0,2,4,6 they all return #text.

```
<ul id="third" >
    <li id="kk"><a href="#" id="pi">Menu 1A</a></li>
    <li id="gg"><a href="#" id="li">Menu 1B</a></li>
    <li id='ff'><a href="#" id="gi">Menu 1C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

They're text nodes holding the whitespace (newlines, spaces) between the end of the `ul` and `li` tags (`>`) and the opening of the next tag (`<`).

If your code was thus:

```
<ul id="third"><li id="kk"><a href="#" id="pi">Menu 1A</a></li><li id="gg"><a href="#" id="li">Menu 1B</a></li><li id='ff'><a href="#" id="gi">Menu 1C</a></li></ul>
```

Those extra text nodes wouldn't be present.